# What could live inside a pillow?

Tags: entomology

I have a phobia of bugs (or other small creatures) living inside my pillow and crawling into my ear in the night. It might seem silly, but bare with me.

Recently I got wondering, what organisms *could* actually live inside a casual foam pillow?
I machine-wash it every now and then to keep it clean.

Comment: Millions of organisms can live in your pillow if you include single-celled organisms (e.g.bacteria) etc. I think this is a bit too broad.

Comment: @anongoodnurse I think it's a better wording to say I'm asking about things that can actually _crawl_ into an ear, question updated. I'm not a bacteriophobe.

Comment: do you want an honest answer ;)

Comment: @ChrisStronks It affects the way I sleep already anyway so I can't really see any further damage being done.

Answer (score 1):

Bed bugs ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bed_bug))! However, you will definitely be able to notice when they are around by bite marks and blood residues.

Comment: @anongoodnurse - I am afraid I am not following you :-) Language barrier perhaps - 1. *Elections kick the stuffing out of one* - you think this is a bad answer? In fact it is haha. Or do you mean Mad Scientist is leaving us? 2. *I lost one as well* - did you loose a mod ship? 3. I am running for mod :-)